# Storage symlink pointing to local storage directory in docker container

Tags: php, docker, laravel-9

I'm following the Laravel documentation for using Laravel with Docker with using the Getting Started section: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos. I use this curl command: `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash` to create the project and then I run `sail up` to create the docker containers, which works fine.

The issue happens when I come to work with the storage folder. I'm following this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk. I run `php artisan storage:link` which creates this item in the links array:

```
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

However, when I go to localhost and try and retrieve an asset by just entering the URL, I get a 404 error. I went into the docker container to see if the symlink was actually created. This is the output: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root root   79 Dec 28 11:29 storage -> /Users/ex_user/example-app/storage/app/public`. It points to my local storage directory, so I ran `php artisan storage:link` inside of the container and the output of the alias was this: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root root   32 Dec 28 11:47 storage -> /var/www/html/storage/app/public`. The images then load correctly. So how can I solve this without have to run the command within the docker container, I do want the project to be able to work if somebody wants to run it without the docker container. I haven't changed anything with my project, this is a fresh pull from the Laravel CURL request so I don't know if this is a bug that needs to be fixed. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

I've tried changing the paths and creating a symlink within the container, but this is not the optimal solution

Comment: I'm not actually sure this will work, but can you try creating the symlink using `php artisan storage:link --relative` (requires `symfony/filesystem` to be installed as a dependency)? This should create a symlink to a relative path (e.g. `../storage/app/public`) instead of the absolute path. That relative symlink should work inside your Docker container as well as on your host.

Comment: You're a life saver thank you, this worked. This should be always done like this with relative paths

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Since it did work, I added it as an answer because comments cannot be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the storage: link from outside of your container, the symlink will be relative to your local machine. Get into the container by running: docker exec -it name_of_your_php_container bashes

Answer (score 1):

The command `php artisan storage:link` creates absolute symbolic links by default.

To create *relative* symbolic links instead, use `php artisan storage:link --relative`. This requires that the `symfony/filesystem` dependency is installed.